# Скролл блока div после определенного количества записей

Tags: javascript, прокрутка

Есть блок

```
<h3>Table of counterpartys</h3>

<div class="table" >
    <table border="1" width="1200" cellspacing="0" id="table_firms">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th><th>Transaction id</th>
        </tr>
        <%-firms%>
    </table>
</div>
```

В нем  у меня появляется прокрутка

```
table tr td{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Но мне нужно сделать так, чтобы этот скролл появлялся после определенного количества записей(например 100) В фронтенде слаб так что прошу помощи

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так при добавлении и удалении узлов

```
function checkCountRow(parentNode, count){       
  if(parentNode.childElementCount >= count){
    if(parentNode.style.height == ""){
        setHeight(parentNode, parentNode.offsetHeight);
    }
  }
  else{
    if(parentNode.style.height != ""){
        resetHeight(parentNode);
    }
  }
}
function setHeight(node, height){
    node.style.height = height + "px";
}
function resetHeight(node){
    node.style.height = ""
}
```